# Can't understand this error using Xcart

Tags: .htaccess, x-cart

We have a website which is built on Xcart 5.2. I imported database on my local system then I set database configuration under **rootfolder/etc/config.php** after that when I go to site using url "localhost/FSM/"

It showing :-

[image]

**config.php**

```
; <?php /*
; WARNING: Do not change the line above
;
; +-------------------------------------+
; |   X-Cart 5 configuration file   |
; +-------------------------------------+
;
; -----------------
;  About this file
; -----------------
;

;
; ----------------------
;  SQL Database details
; ----------------------
;
[database_details]
hostspec = "localhost"
socket = "/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock"
port = "3306"
database = "florist_singapore"
username = "root"
password = ""
table_prefix = "xc_"

;
; ----------------------
;  Cache settings
; ----------------------
;
[cache]
; Type of cache used. Can take auto, memcache, apc, xcache, file values.
type=file
; Cache namespace
namespace=XLite
; List of memcache servers. Semicolon is used as a delimiter.
; Each server is specified with a host name and port number, divided
; by a colon. If the port is not specified, the default
; port 11211 is used.
servers=

;
; -----------------------------------------------------------------------
;  X-Cart 5 HTTP & HTTPS host, web directory where cart installed
;  and allowed domains
; -----------------------------------------------------------------------
;
; NOTE:
; You should put here hostname ONLY without http:// or https:// prefixes
; Do not put slashes after the hostname
; Web dir is the directory in the URL, not the filesystem path
; Web dir must start with slash and have no slash at the end
; The only exception is when you configure for the root of the site,
; in which case you write single slash in it
; Domains should be listed separated by commas.
;
; WARNING: Do not set the "$" sign before the parameter names!
;
; EXAMPLE 1:
;
;   http_host = "www.yourhost.com"
;   https_host = "www.securedirectories.com/yourhost.com"
;   web_dir = "/shop"
;   domains = "www.yourhost2.com,yourhost3.com"
;
; will result in the following URLs:
;
;   http://www.yourhost.com/shop
;   https://www.securedirectories.com/yourhost.com/shop
;
;
; EXAMPLE 2:
;
;   http_host = "www.yourhost.com"
;   https_host = "www.yourhost.com"
;   web_dir = "" (don't use "/")
;
; will result in the following URLs:
;
;   http://www.yourhost.com
;   https://www.yourhost.com
;
[host_details]
http_host = "localhost"
https_host = "localhost"
web_dir = "/FSM"
domains = ""

[clean_urls]
; String with one or more chars.
; It will be used to autogenerate clean URLs.
; By default, only the "-" or "_" characters are allowed.
; Empty string is also allowed.
default_separator = "-"

; Get clean URLs capitalized for every starting letter of a word
capitalize_words = Off

; Use canonical URL for product page
use_canonical_urls_only = On

;
; -----------------
;  Logging details
; -----------------
;
[log_details]
type = file
name = "var/log/xlite.log.php"
level = LOG_WARNING
ident = "XLite"
suppress_errors = On
suppress_log_errors = Off

;
; Skin details
;
[skin_details]
skin = default
locale = en

;
; Default image settings
;
[images]
default_image = "images/no_image.png"
default_image_width = 110
default_image_height = 110
unsharp_mask_filter_on_resize = off

; Installation path of Image Magick executables:
; for example:
; image_magick_path = "C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.7.0-Q16\\"   (in Windows)
; image_magick_path = "/usr/local/imagemagick/" (in Unix/Linux )
; You should consult with your hosting provider to find where Image Magick is installed
; If you leave it empty then PHP GD library will be used.
;
image_magick_path =

;
; Installer authcode.
; A person who do not know the auth code can not access the installation script.
; Installation authcode is created authomatically and stored in this section.
;
[installer_details]
auth_code = "3JT6GWX7"
shared_secret_key = "55a77ea79a7c93.31452261"

;
; Some options to optimize the store
;
[performance]
developer_mode = Off
skins_cache = off
compress_php_core = off

;
; Decorator options
;
[decorator]
time_limit = 600
use_tokenizer = Off
disable_software_reset = Off
use_output = Off
quick_data_rebuilding = Off

;
; Error handling options
;
[error_handling]
; Template for error pages
page = "public/error.html"
page_customer = "public/customer/error.html"
; Template for maintenance pages
maintenance = "public/maintenance.html"

;
; Marketplace
;
[marketplace]
url = "http://my.x-cart.com/index.php?q=api"
log_data = Off
upgrade_step_time_limit = 240
banner_url = "http://my.x-cart.com/xcinfo"

;
; Language options
;
[language]
default = en

;
; Installation parameters
;
[installation]
installation_lng = en

;
; AMQP server
;
[amqp]
host     = "localhost"
port = "3306"
user     = "guest"
password = ""
vhost    = "/"
exchange = "xlite"

;
; HTML Purifier options
; See http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html for more details on HTML Purifier options
;
[html_purifier]
; Allow link 'target' attribute
Attr.AllowedFrameTargets = On

; List of allowed values for 'target' attribute
Attr.AllowedFrameTargets[] = _blank
Attr.AllowedFrameTargets[] = _self
Attr.AllowedFrameTargets[] = _top
Attr.AllowedFrameTargets[] = _parent

; Allow 'id' attribute
Attr.EnableID = On

; Allow embed tags
HTML.SafeEmbed = On

; Allow object tags
HTML.SafeObject = On

; Allow iframe tags
HTML.SafeIframe = On

; List of allowed URI (without http:// or https:// part) for iframe tags
; If there are no allowed URIs specified then any src will be allowed for iframe tags
;
; Examples:
;
; URI.SafeIframeRegexp[] = "www.youtube.com/embed/"
; URI.SafeIframeRegexp[] = "www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/"
; URI.SafeIframeRegexp[] = "player.vimeo.com/video/"

;
; Other options
;
[other]
; Translation drive code - auto / gettext / db
translation_driver = auto
; Event driver code - auto / db / amqp
event_driver = auto

; List of trusted domains.
; This option prevents redirecting to untrusted URLs passed via returnURL parameter.
; Examples:
; trusted_domains = "google.com"
; trusted_domains = "google.com, yahoo.com"
trusted_domains =

; X-Frame-Options value
; For possible values see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options
; Examples:
; x_frame_options = 'disabled'
; x_frame_options = 'sameorigin'
x_frame_options = 'sameorigin'

; WARNING: Do not change the line below
; */ ?>
```

**.htaccess** at root folder

```
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex cart.php
FileETag none

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # #BUG-772 Add HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header for fastCGI (need for XC\Qiwi)
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
  RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

  RewriteRule (^|/)\. - [F]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml(\?.+)?$ cart.php?target=sitemap [NC,L,QSA]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^((([/_a-z0-9-]+)/)?([_a-z0-9-]+)/)?([_a-z0-9-]+)(/?)(\.([_a-z0-9-]+))?$ cart.php?url=$5&last=$4&rest=$3&ext=$7 [NC,L,QSA]

  RewriteBase /FSM
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

  # Expire images/js/css header
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault A0

  # Images expires in 2 weeks
  ExpiresByType image/png A1209600
  ExpiresByType image/gif A1209600
  ExpiresByType image/jpg A1209600
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg A1209600
  ExpiresByType image/ico A1209600
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon A1209600

  # CSS/JS now work with dynamic unique query string. 1 year expires
  ExpiresByType text/css A31104000
  ExpiresByType text/javascript A31104000
  ExpiresByType application/javascript A31104000

</IfModule>

# Clean URLs [[[
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(payment|admin|provider|partner)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatcher.php [L]

#/Clean URLs
```

I doubt it may be issue of .htaccess so I shared this files too Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: I voted to close this question because a 500 error is a very generic "something went wrong" error. It could be a misconfiguration, a permissions problem, or a coding error. More information about the specific cause of your error is available in your server's error log. There is no way to accurately answer this question without seeing the logs. Any answers here will be guesses and there are hundreds if not thousands of possible answers.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please share the `var/log/php_errors.log.<date>.php` and `xlite.log.<date>.php` files?

The actual error should be there. Also, yon can set `suppress_errors = Off` and `developer_mode = On` in the `etc/config.php` file and run X-Cart again to see if it shows the actual error right in the browser.

You can check out the http://kb.x-cart.com/en/general_setup/moving_x-cart_to_another_location.html tutorial to see if you've completed each step correctly.

Comment: hello @Eugene thanks for reply but there are no logs and I have follow all the steps according to tutorial. Your all three solutions didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Eugene's request is correct - not possible to help with this issue without the extra info.